# Term for catchy tune that stays in your head

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

Is there a term for a catchy tune that stays in your head after you hear it? The Germans call it an *earworm*.

Comment: The German word is *Ohrwurm*.

Comment: I call it "Back in Black." :-)

Comment: Mark Twain wrote the [short story](http://www.readbookonline.net/readOnLine/559/) *Punch, Brothers, Punch* about this phenomenon, but didn't have a specific name for it. I have heard *earworm* used for it for quite a while, although I don't know when the earliest usage I heard was.

Comment: Unfortunately, the corn earworm totally swamps any search for the term "earworm" or "ear worm", but "earworm" is the term I have used for a decade, at least.

Comment: I am reminded that there was a Star Trek episode (likely in [TNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek#The_Next_Generation_(1987%E2%80%9394)) from 1987-94) where some sort of worm would enter a victim's ear and take over their brain.  To the large number of young people who saw this episode "earworm" would have a strong association, making it "catch on".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have never heard of a single word, but the phrase "stuck in your head" comes to mind.

Answer (score 29):

In English it is called *earworm* or *sticky tune*.

Comment: Sticky tune? May I ask where you heard that? I don't remember running across it in the U.S.

Comment: I've heard it called earworm in English, but I know that's a direct translation of the German.

Comment: +1 I did not know that was a German-origin term

Comment: I've never heard of either of these words.

Comment: @mmyers: The definition "sticky tune" can be seen on [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/earworm). Some friends of mine use it.

Comment: "Earworm" as an English word is a bit of a neologism, but catching on fast. I heard it about ten years ago. I didn't know it was a calque from German though.

Comment: I always thought the word for this was "catchy tune".

Comment: @Kosmonaut: See the definition in [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/earworm).

Comment: @Mehper: I understand that "earworm" exists in the dictionary, since you already linked to it once; I am trying to consider what people actually say.  I have heard people use the phrase "catchy tune"  to describe such a phenomenon hundreds — if not thousands — of times in my life, but I have never heard "earworm" used once.

Comment: I can attest to 'earworm' in use amongst university students in England around the turn of the century. 'Seven Nation Army' was our canonical example, because of that amazing, insistent, repeating bass phrase it's built on. How old is the German usage? Could hat be a calque from English?

Comment: @Tom Anderson: See the [blog post here](http://bearcastle.com/blog/?p=149). It's pretty clear that the English came from the German, although it's unclear which instance of translation is the one that caught on.

Comment: @Kosmonaut - I've heard `earworm` "in the wild". I heard it from my choir director about a month ago. So someone acquainted with music, but also someone living in the middle of Oklahoma. If the word made it here, it's everywhere. :-)

Comment: I just watched an episode of Sponge Bob titled "Earworm".

Comment: Upvote for _earworm_; downvote for _sticky tune_. Separate this into two answers?

Answer (score 5):

Most songs, especially of the pop variety, tend to contain a "hook" which is designed to, well, hook into your mind. Not quite the answer to your question but a part of it. You can [read more about musical hooks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_%28music%29) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Perhaps songs like this ought to be known as "hookers". Oh wait, that's something quite different...

Answer (score 4):

Jingle.

Having said which, I prefer to use "earworm" these days because "jingle" has such an overwhelming association with advertising.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes the word "brainwashed" is used to express the state of having a tune stuck in one's head:

> I'm brainwashed with that tune

Note that applies to the state of the person, not to the tune itself.