# Pronunciation of "of"

Tags: pronunciation, weak-forms

Is "of" always supposed to be pronounced with the v sound (like "ov")? Or does it depend on the region (e.g. US, UK) or maybe on the word that follows the preposition?

For example, how would you pronounce the title of this question?

Comment: “Is "of" always supposed to be pronounced with the v sound?”  Of course.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi, why "of course"?

Comment: The word “of” in the phrase “of course” is usually pronounced with the /f/ sound.  That is, my previous comment was meant to be a joke. :(

Comment: That's an interesting answer to the question then. The fact that there are exceptions should be highlighted in our answers here.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi - I have never ever heard 'of course' pronounced with /f/. Are you talking about 'off course'?

Comment: @Colin: I do not think that I am confusing “of course” with “off course,” but my understanding about the pronunciation of “of course” turned out to be incorrect.  See my answer.

Comment: I think it's because of the 'v' sound that the trend towards could of/should of/would of (instead of have) has arrisen

Comment: Sometimes the *v* sound is omitted completely ... **lotsa luck**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In English (well, OK, UK, US, Australian and NZ English, at least, but I suspect all English), "of" is pronounced with the 'v' sound, as "ov". This helps to distinguish it from "off", a separate word (meaning "not on"), pronounced with the 'f' sound.

Comment: Hence the crime against humanity that is "should of".

Comment: @RegDwight, do you mean the misspelling that is derived from how people pronounce "should have"?

Comment: @Bruno - I think it is actually should've, which is totally valid. Some people just spell it wrong when writing it down.

Comment: @gkrogers: I agree that the [v] sound is used in all these dialects of English, but I don't agree that the reason is to distinguish it from *off*.  *Of* and *off* have different vowel sounds in addition to their consonants being different, so the [v] or [f] wouldn't make a difference.  But even if this weren't the case, homophony is common even among high-frequency words.  Take *two/too/to* or *they're/their/there*, for example.  I think it is just pronounced that way "because it is", and it is spelled that way because it used to be pronounced with an [f] sound at one time.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: yes, you're right - that's not the _reason_, per se. I should've just said "This helpfully distinguishes it from..."

Comment: @gkrogers: OK, but I was saying that the consonant doesn't distinguish the two words either.  They would be different with the same final consonant.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: I don't agree that they would be different even with the same consonant. The vowel sounds are identical.

Comment: @gkrogers: The vowels are just plain not the same.  The difference between the vowels in *of* and *off* is the same difference that we use to distinguish *but* and *bot*, for example.  You can look at the dictionary pronunciation if you don't believe me: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of and http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off

Comment: Ah, I see! You're referring to US pronunciation; I'm referring to British English, or "RP". The OED has the pronunciation of 'of' as "ɒv" and of 'off' as "ɒf".

Comment: This is a good point. It is pronounced with the V sound. If it had an F sound, it would be the word "off" which is a different word with a different meaning.

Answer (score 8):

The word *of* is often pronounced weakly, and the /v/ sound at the end of *of* is sometimes pronounced as [f].  The phrase “of course” is a typical example.  I think that the /v/ in the word *of* is often pronounced as [f] before an unvoiced consonant.

Honestly speaking, this came as a surprise to me.  As a foreign speaker, I learned the following “rule” at school: the word *of* in the phrase *of course* is pronounced with the “f” sound.  (A similar “rule” is that the word *have* in *have to* is pronounced with the “f” sound.)  Learning it as a rule had given me a (wrong) impression that English speakers are *aware* of it.  However, while looking for a material to back up this “rule,” I learned that this is merely a variation of the actual sound of the same phoneme /v/.

Comment: Ah, I see. I remember coming across a suggestion that voiced consonants in English are generally only half voiced, and the major difference is fortis/lenis rather than voice.

Comment: Actually I think you are right about the /f/ sound in /of course/. If I say it slowly I put the /v/ in there, but in the course of a sentence I do say a soft /f/; /fc/ must be easier on the lips than /vc/.

Comment: I tried saying it at a more normal speed and still ended up with "A horse is a horse, ov course, ov course."  And now I have a different problem: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/810

Comment: Tsuyoshi Ito, that is a surprise. Maybe because it's not a “rule” but a variation in how different people pronounce that particular, letter *f*. It's always amusing to learn of things in the language that non-native speakers have assumed or have been led to believe are strict rules, followed religiously, when in reality, they are not.

Comment: The normal will be a /v/ for both *of* and *have*, but /v/ in front of certain voiceless consonants will devoice to /f/ in moderately fast speech (at least in many dialects).

Answer (score 5):

It depends. Formally it's always "ov." But it can be shortened to "a", like if you say someone is a "piece a shit", or "cream a the crop."

Some following words lend themselves better to shortening. For example, saying "I've heard a him" is less common (for me anyway) than "I've heard ov him."

Comment: In my dialect, we'd be most likely to shorten this to "I've heard've 'im" [ɑɪv hɝd ə vəm].  So, the [h] in *him* is dropped (which is regularly done with *him* and *her*), leaving no need to drop the [v] from *of*.

Comment: @ Claudiu Or "cream o' the crop" or "ring a ring o' roses".
@Kosmonaut But hopefully never written "heard've". Just "I've heard of 'im".

Comment: The apostrophe in *o'clock* is of similar origin.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Longman Pronunciation Dictionary, the strong form is pronounced as [ɒv] (British) / [ʌv] (US), whereas the weak form is pronounced as [əv]. The informal short form, sometimes written as o', is pronounced as [ə]. There is no mentioning of any exceptions, suggesting that the of in "of course" (cf. other answers and comments) is pronounced in the same way (not with f). Audio files can be found [here](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/of). The dictionary points out that "of" is a rare exception of a word where f is pronounced like v.

Comment: Wow ... I never realized the strong form was pronounced differently in England. Of course, you almost never hear the strong form.

Comment: Yeah, me neither. I’d love to find some audio clips of actual speech wherein this is demonstrated.

Comment: @tchrist: I would use the stressed form about half the time in “What’re you thinking of?” [… θɪŋkɪŋ ʌv] (depending on prosody) and all the time in “Pronunciation of ‘of’” [… əv ʌv].