# Why does the dictionary give the pronunciation of the word "of" as '\əv' with a 'v' sound when in some cases it's pronounced with 'f' sound?

Tags: prepositions, pronunciation, accent, sounds

"of" seems to be pronounced with the f sound asˈäf in phrases like "of course". But 'of' is pronounced as \əv in a lot of other cases.

Yet, Merriam Websters gives the one with 'v' sound as the only pronunciation.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of

Why is that? Why does the dictionary give the one with 'v' sound as the only pronunciation?

In what cases 'of' is pronounced with f versus pronounced with v sound?

Comment: I pronounce "of course" with the 'v' sound. That said, dictionaries may not cover all regional accents.

Comment: Words can be pronounced in all kinds of ways in combination with each other. The dictionary just describes the basic pronunciation of a word, and maybe a few common variants: it won't tell you all of the ways it can change depending on the surrounding words. You are probably just hearing non-phonemic devoicing of the word-final "lenis" obstruent /v/ before a voiceless consonant (/k/), as described in the answer to [Are “whores” and “horse” homophones?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/342273) This is a type of o a native speaker, this generally still sounds like /v/, not /f/.

Comment: Can you give some examples of where the pronunciation with /f/ is used? I've never heard it from a native speaker and I've heard quite a lot of different accents. Even fluent speakers of English as a second language don't do it IME, though they might confuse /f/ and /v/ at other times. And *of course* being a homophone for *off course* doesn't seem likely.

Comment: Sorry about the mangled last sentence: I ran out of time while editing my previous comment. I meant to say "This is a type of partial phonetic assimilation" and "To a native speaker, this generally still sounds like /v/, not /f/." As Chris H says, an audio example would be helpful.

Comment: When does it have an "f" pronunciation???

Comment: "Heard of it" has more of a 'v' than "more of a" or "of course".

Comment: @sumelic I have heard a clear "f" sound in "of course" from native american english speakers often. To find a sample I simply searched on youtube and this is one of the top links that shows up. Notice clear "f" sound at 0:08, 0:10, 0:25 seconds. (at other times it's just o'course but it's f sound at various instances too). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YwxnWi3mn6o

Comment: @chris posted an example in other comment.

Comment: Related: [Pronunciation of “of”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/pronunciation-of-of), [Is “of” pronounced as “ov”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/401126)

Comment: @JoeBlack really? You're going to use *that* video as demonstrating normal everyday pronunciation? Anyway, even though that's hardly normal speech, I don't hear an invoiced F before any of his versions of 'of course'.

Comment: @clare really? can you say what's wrong with the video? the speaker is a well read speaker without any strong accent. i do hear an 'f' in _several_ of his 'of courses' (but not all as i commented before), whose occurrence times in the video i specified in the comment earlier.

Answer (score 3):

"Of" doesn't have "f" sound. It's always pronounced as "əv" to distinguish it from the word "off" which then is pronounced as "f" .

Bear in mind that I am referring to General English ( RP) the one taught in schools. We call it received pronunciation or RP in British English and that's the pronunciation similar to any dictionaries.

Regional pronunciation is another debate...

Comment: This isn't the right answer. *Of course* is often pronounced with [f], because the phoneme /v/ turns into [f] when followed by some voiceless consonants. You're saying the OP isn't hearing things that he really is. Native English speakers' ears are trained to recognize this as a /v/ anyway.

Comment: There may be some dialects where the F is pronounced more clearly as an F, but as a native Canadian English speaker who has heard many of the dialects, I confess that I have not heard this pronunciation in the wild.

Comment: @PeterShor I pronounce the *of* in *of course* the same way I pronounce it in *of all*, *of Toronto*, *of the Village People*.  Your pronunciation may be dialectical.

Comment: The two people from the UK on [forvo.com](https://forvo.com/word/of_course/#en) seem like they're saying *uf course* to me. Of course, it's possible they're using a consonant partway between an [f] and a [v]. But this could still confuse the OP.

Comment: I would say OF COURSE is pronounced as any other OF, no exception. But then for some people there is a confusion between the sound F and V.  In general pronunciation the " V " is a voiced sound whereas the "F" is voiceless. Nevertheless, between natives it's hard to distinguish but we do naturally voice or not voice the sound even though it's hard to hear. Indeed, in the UK we pronounce it in 2 different ways but only in regards to the syllable  "ɒv" OR "əv"

Comment: 'of course' does get pronounced with the f sound by native AmE speakers and not just regionally. in trump speech you often hear a full [f] sound in "of course" sometimes along with the o'course pronunciation. i posted an example audio in other comment.

Comment: @peterShor it sounds like a clear [f] sound among many native AmE speakers also when they say "of course" unlike the typical pronunciation of "of" with the v sound.

Comment: I do not think that Mr Trump is the best example to represent AmE speakers as he seems to limit himself to 20% of English vocabulary to talk.

Comment: @nissa yours is a rhetorical statement about trump, but his pronunciation of 'of course' is not unique to him and occurs throughout US even though he has an ny accent. i posted an audio example in other comment.

Comment: @PeterShor I listened to the Forvo examples and they all sound like a voiced /uv/ to me before 'course'.

Comment: @peterShor as an example, this is the 'f' sound in of course of a native speaker without strong regional accent.  To find a sample I simply searched on youtube and this is one of the top links that shows up. Notice clear "f" sound at 0:08, 0:10, 0:25 seconds. (at other times it's just o'course but it's f sound at various instances too).  http://youtube.com/watch?v=YwxnWi3mn6o

Comment: @PeterShor There seem to be more examples on Forvo now. If I try to hear them as /f/, I hear all the British and US examples as /f/, and only the Australian one as /v/. If I'm not trying to hear them as /f/, I hear them all as /v/.