# Is "of" pronounced as "ov"?

Tags: word-usage, pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, spelling-pronunciations

Few years back, one of our English teachers told that,

> *In India, we [typically] pronounce "of" as "of" or "off". But the real pronunciation is "ov".*

When I try to listen the same in Google dictionary, it indeed sounds like "ov" :-). But I am not sure, if I am listening it correctly.

Since my native language is not English, can someone suggest what is the right pronunciation?
If it's really "ov" then it would be interesting to know, why is it so?

It has also been mentioned that this word has different vowels according to its environment. Is this true?

Comment: @Cascabel, from the comment of "marcell", I realised that the way I wrote may create the confusion. The teacher's saying is just a backdrop of the Qn. I would really like to know, how to pronounce "of". If it's really "ov", then it will be interesting to know why so?

Comment: If you wish to discuss pronunciation on an international forum the International Phonetic Alphabet is really indispensable; [this](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:IPA_pronunciation_key) may help.

Comment: The right pronounciation is in dictionary and it is _(ŭv, ŏv; əv when unstressed)_ http://www.thefreedictionary.com/OF  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of

Comment: @Alex: First, that's the ***American*** pronunciation. Second, I'm American and I don't know if I've ever heard anybody say /ɑv/ (ŏv). In my experience, it is almost always /ʌv/ (ŭv), and /əv/ when unstressed. The British say /ɒv/, or /əv/ when unstressed.

Comment: If *of* doesn't rhyme with *love* and *dove*, I've been pronouncing it wrong for my entire speaking life.

Comment: @Davo: For a number of British English speakers, the word "of" when stressed rhymes with the second syllable of "improv". But the pronunciation you mention is common among American English speakers.

Comment: Is "of" really pronounced like "off" in India?

Comment: @bof, Yes it's either "of" or sometimes "off", when indeed stressed :-). Our native languages are quite different from English. They are written exactly as they are supposed to be pronounced. However in English, 50-50% chances are there, if the written form and the pronunciation would match.

Comment: @Davo you must have a strong British accent

Comment: Related: [Why do people pronounce the word “of” as if it's “ov”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/124997)

Comment: @tjt263 what Davo stated is the exact polar opposite of most British accents, notably including RP. What are you even on about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**British English**

The word *of* has a strong form, /ɒv/. This has the same vowel we hear in the word *lot*, /lɒt/. This form of the word ends with a 'v' sound.

We use the strong form of *of* when it is stressed and also when it occurs with out a following complement. So in the phrase *What are you thinking of?*, there is no noun phrase following the word *of*, and we will hear the  strong form used.

However, when the word *of* is not stressed and does have a following complement (usually a noun phrase), native speakers will use a weak form of the word. In such a case, the word might be realised as any of the following:

- əv
- v
- ə

So the phrase *lots of people* may be realised as any of the following:

- lɒts əv pi:pl
- lɒts v pi:pl
- lɒts ə pi:pl

**American Englishes**

In some varieties of American English, the strong form of the word *of* uses the vowel /ʌ/. This is the vowel we find in the word *strut*. Some dictionaries give both pronunciations [/ʌv/ and /ɑv/](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/401126/is-of-pronounced-as-ov/401136?noredirect=1#comment953512_401136)

---

<sup>I've used a British English transcription here, but nothing much hinges on that.</sup>

Comment: Not so sure _of course_ is really that relevant as an exceptional thing. I can quite easily produce _lots of people_ with an [f] as well, as well as _of course_ with a [v]. It’s simply a matter of the /v/ optionally assimilating to a following unvoiced consonant.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Ah, but can you pronounce *of course* with a /v/ ? ;)

Comment: As opposed to with an /f/ or a [v]? I’m not sure (mostly because I can’t figure out if there’d ever be any difference)!

Comment: I'm not sure that anyone actually ever says  /ɑv/ with their FATHER vowel there, but certainly there are American dialects (especially in the Northeast) that have a rounded vowel on the stressed version, **but** I don't know that they distinguish the CLOTH vowel from the THOUGHT vowel. For me, those are both /ɔ/ (I have a CLOTH–THOUGHT merger to /ɔ/ and a COT–FATHER merger to /ɑ/ but ***not*** a COT–CAUGHT merger of /ɑ/ and  /ɔ/) so I couldn't tell you whether for example Pittsburgers were "really" saying one or another of /ɒv/ or  /ɔv/. I know no minimal pair between  /ɒ/ and  /ɔ/ either.

Answer (score 1):

The English word pronounced /of/ is the noun *oaf*, a pejorative term for a stupid, uncultured, or clumsy person.

The English preposition *of* is pronounced /ʌv/, /əv/, or /ə/ depending on where it’s used.

The first of those is the least common because that is a stressed vowel but the word is almost never stressed the way it might be in a spoken list of actual words like *to, from, of, about*. This gives it the same sound as heard in the words *love, dove, glove*, where those all start with consonants but end with the strong pronunciation of *of*: /lʌv/, /dʌv/, /glʌv/.

The second of those with the unstressed schwa is the most common. Use /əv/ in most situations.

Nonetheless the third is hardly rare. It naturally occurs in all but the very most precise and deliberate of elocutions. Most spoken instances of *of* are actually this lone /ə/. If you were playing cards and someone mentioned that they had a *six of clubs*, that would come out just like the clock-time *six o’clock* is pronounced, save for the /lʌbz/ part at the end of the card. It’s common in any *XXX of the ZZZ* type of construction as well as in *a lot of XXX* or in *a bunch of XXX* ones. You’re left with nothing but a weak and barely distinguishable /ə/; hence the eye-dialect spelling of *lotta* sometimes seen in phrases like “a whole lotta love”

Comment: Is this for AmEng? In AusEng "of" doesn't rhyme with "love", and from comments above it seems that would be the case for BrEng too.

Comment: @curiousdannii Oxford Dictionaries Online disagrees: [they give *love* as /lʌv/](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/love). Hence also [*luvvie* as /ˈlʌvi/](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/luvvie). That’s the STRUT vowel using [standard lexical sets per Wells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_set#Wells_Standard_Lexical_Sets_for_English), not the FOOT or CLOTH or THOUGHT etc vowels. Actual phonetics will of course [vary considerably](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects) — and even that last is grossly simplified.

Comment: @tchrist I think what Curiousdanni is getting at is probably that *of* doesn't have a STRUT vowel in Aussie English.

Comment: @tchrist Yep "love" has the unrounded STRUT  /ʌ/ but in AusEng at least "of" has the rounded CLOTH /ɒ/.

Comment: @Araucaria So what’s the centralized version of that which preserves rounding then for unstressed/weak contexts? [Do you mean **ɞ** then?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_central_rounded_vowel) Does that roundedness trait actually survive in unstressed use instead of becoming a simple schwa with all traits levelled off?

Comment: Note that [ODO also gives /ɒv/](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/of) as the stressed pronunciation of _of_ (and /əv/ as the unstressed one). I’m fairly certain BrE and AuE agree here, though of course the actual realisations of /ɒ/ and /ə/ vary somewhat.

Comment: @tchrist It's just a schwa (unrounded) when unstressed in BE. Not sure about AUSE though.

Comment: @curiousdannii In EngEng "of" rhymes with "love" or at least it did in the 1860s for poet A. C. Swinburne: "For the Gods we know not ***of***, who give us our daily breath, / We know they are cruel as ***love*** or life, and lovely as death. [. . .] Time and the Gods are at strife: ye dwell in the midst there***of***, / Draining a little life from the barren breasts of ***love***."

Comment: @bof what's most interesting about Swinburne is that he was from London and educated at Eton and Oxford. So we can probably assume RP, rather than a regional accent that might routinely rhyme *of* with *love*. I don't think this was standard in RP, at least by the time of his death (we have recordings from that long ago) so it may have been a poetic use.

Comment: @ChrisH Yeah, maybe it was poetic. ACS also rhymed *river* with *never*: "From too much love of living, / From hope and fear set free, / We thank with brief thanksgiving / Whatever gods may be / That no life lives forever; / That dead men rise up never; / That even the weariest river / Winds somewhere safe to sea."

Comment: @bof without tracking down vintage recordings to check, I'd say that *river*/*ever* as a rhyme works in posh English of the early 20th century.

Answer (score 0):

I think we pronounce it as (ov) because o has a vibration in the vocal cords, then this affects the sound "f" and pronounces as "v"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).