# How do we call the act of mumbling a song throughout the day?

Tags: single-word-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Term for catchy tune that stays in your head](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/810/term-for-catchy-tune-that-stays-in-your-head)

If we listen to a song in the morning, we'll mumble the lyrics of the song throughout the day.How do we call it in English?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's called an *[earworm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earworm)*.  The song is stuck in your head all day like a burrowed worm.

> An earworm is a piece of music that sticks in one's mind so that one
>   seems to hear it, even when it is not being played.